# Xcode 15: No such module 'FirebaseDatabase'

Tags: ios, firebase, cocoapods, geofire, xcode15

The same project compiles fine on my Intel MacBook pro, but on my M1 Pro running Sonoma and Xcode 15 RC, it gives `No such module 'FirebaseDatabase'` error.

[image]

Here is how my pod file looks like:

[image]

I made sure the Minimum Deployments is 13.0 on all firebase pods:

[image]

I can't use swift package manager for these dependencies because GeoFire would cause problems.

Comment: 1. Please avoid posting code as images.
2. Not sure if it's going to help, but use the modern way to install Firebase pods: instead of `pod Firebase/Database` write `pod FirebaseDatabase`. More details on the pod names in the docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup#available-pods. 3. Make sure to upgrade Firebase pods to the latest version by running `pod update FirebaseDatabase`.

Comment: Thank you, but changing the pod declaration and updating didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by removing `arm64` from Excluded Architectures
[image]
[image]

I think Xcode 15 added this automatically for the simulator to work on Apple silicon M1 machines in projects with CocoaPods dependencies.

Also worth mentioning that I faced other problems, but were fixed using `pod update` and NOT `pod install`